# how to update data only if the sql query we have entered exists through python?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to update one table in mysql which has 3 rows

what i want is to update any row with update command but this has to be happened only when there exists a particular row
i.e.if i update it like updatedata = "update table12 set name='Dhiraj', city='Delhi' where id=**25**"

then it should give me an error

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect('localhost','root','','firstdb')
print("database connected successfully")
cur = db.cursor()
updatedata = "update table12 set name='Dhiraj', city='delhi' where id=25"
if updatedata:
    try:
        cur.execute(updatedata)
        db.commit()
        print("Data updated successfully...")
    except:
        print("Something went wrong!")                
else:
    print("There is no any data you entered!")
```

Comment: so your update is to updaet inly rows that have the id 25 if you make a `where id <>25` all except 25 get updated. It is quite unclear what you want to do

Comment: Check the `cur.rowcount` attribute

Comment: there is only 3 rows in table...if i try to update any row which does not exist in table...let's say row number 5(which does not exist) then else part has to be executed...thats all i want

Comment: try to use updatedata = "update table12 set name='Dhiraj', city='delhi' where id=25;" i just add semicolen to the code.    upvote if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cur.execute()` returns the number of affected rows:
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute

So you should be able to do something like:

```py
updated_rows = cur.execute(updatedata)
if updated_rows > 0:
  print("success")
else:
  print("no matching rows")
```

Answer (score 0):

This updates all rows based on a condition over the same table

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET field_to_update = CASE
   WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl) AS copy WHERE copy.field=<condition> HAVING COUNT(*)>0) THEN "this_value_if_true"
   ELSE field_to_update
END
```